# Scroll to a particular card position when clicked on a marker on Map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-recyclerview

this is the layout code

```
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    locationRecycler = findViewById(R.id.locations_area);
    locationRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    locationAreaAdapter = new LocationAreaAdapter(this, locations);




public  void callMapPins(){

    for (  markerCount=0 ; markerCount<lat.size();markerCount++){
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(lat.get(markerCount)), Float.parseFloat(lng.get(markerCount)));
       // mgoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney));

      markerId.add( mgoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)).getId()) ;
        mgoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            if(markerId.contains(marker.getId())){
             // Toast.makeText(insideHostelList.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(markerCount);
               //this is not working 

            }

                return false;
            }
        });
        mgoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney,10f));
    }
}
```

Im storing marker id in a array and then when clicking on a  marker comparing the id's and then using the marker count to scroll to a particular postion but it doesn't seems to work can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

Take the OnMarkerClickListener out of the for loop.Set the markerClickListener after you created and added the markers to the map and stored the ids.

```
  public  void callMapPins(){

    for (markerCount=0 ; markerCount<lat.size();markerCount++){

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(lat.get(markerCount)), Float.parseFloat(lng.get(markerCount)));

        markerId.add( mgoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)).getId()) ;
    }


    mgoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            if(markerId.contains(marker.getId())){
                // Toast.makeText(insideHostelList.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              int index = markerId.indexOf(marker.getId());
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(index);
                //this is not working 
                mgoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker.getPosition(),10f));
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```